# Selecting a specific row based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

This might be a trivial question for you experts out there:

Based on the input (Week) the table is initially filtered on that specific week(WK) and the next one(WK+1).
I'm then formatting all WK+1 cells to be greyed out.

So far so good. Now the question. How can I change the code below so that the entire row containing a cell with the WK+1 value to be greyed out?

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B5").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=WK, Operator:=xlOr, _
Criteria2:=(WK + 1)

With ActiveSheet.Range("$B:$B").FormatConditions _
.Add(xlCellValue, xlEqual, "=" & WK + 1)
With .Font
.Bold = True
.ColorIndex = 15
End With
End With
```

Thanks in advance!
Mac

Comment: so you want the text to be grey if I understand you? and why do you have a _ after `.Formatconditions`?

Comment: @Goosebumbs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba9sxbw4.aspx

Comment: no i know what it does, but why does he have it like this, why not .Font on the same line and stuff like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with FormatCondition of type xlExpression.
Example:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$Z").FormatConditions.Delete
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Activate
With ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$Z").FormatConditions _
 .Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=($B1=" & WK + 1 & ")")
 With .Font
  .Bold = True
  .ColorIndex = 15
 End With
End With
```

I delete the FormatConditions before I add the new one. Because if not, multiple calls of this code would result in multiple FormatConditions ever with the same condition but possible other values of WK. This is because the code adds a new FormatCondition everytime it runs.

Greetings

Axel